# Can I power rails with levers in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to tunnel in my world and I'm curious to know if I can activate powered rails by using a lever instead of redstone or redstone torches.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

A [Powered Rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail) can be activated by:

- an adjacent active [power component](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_components#Power_components) (for example, a redstone torch, a block of redstone, a daylight sensor, a lever...)
- an adjacent powered block (strongly-powered or weakly-powered)
- a powered redstone comparator or redstone repeater facing the powered rail
- powered redstone dust configured to point at the powered rail

A Lever is a power component, which is used to switch circuits on or off, or to permanently power a block.